# Fabric js select object in group

Tags: fabricjs

Is it possible to select a single object from a group created like this?

```
var r = new fabric.Rect(...);
var l = new fabric.Line(...);
var roadGroup = new fabric.Group([r,l],{ ... });
```

So I want to have a group, but select objects l or r separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is yes, but you should make sure you take into account the purpose of a group.

To get a handle on an object that is wrapped in a group you can do something like this:

```
var r = roadGroup._objects[0];
var l = roadGroup._objects[1];
```

To *select* a child of a group try something like this:

```
fabricCanvas.setActiveObject(roadGroup._objects[0]);
```

**soapbox**:

The purpose of creating a group is to treat several objects as if they were a single one. The purpose of selecting an object is to allow user interactions with an object. If you want your user to interact with a portion of a group, you might want to consider not grouping them in the first place, or else un-grouping them prior to selecting the child object.

**/soapbox**

Comment: My goals are: 1. User can edit properties of single objects (r,l) through UI. 2. Objects cannot be moved separately, just together. So if you could suggest an other way, it would be great =)

Comment: and one more thing: selection should be occurring by mouse.

Comment: If you want to make the selection with the mouse you'll have to un-group the shapes. You could make a list in your UI that lists sub-elements in the group that would select the sub-element when a row in the list was clicked. Alternatively you could un-group on double click of the group after saving the child list to a standard javascript array. Single clicking a child object would behave as usual. Then create a `canvas.on('selection:created', function(){ ... }` function that would check if one of the un-grouped shapes is now the currently selected object and if not, re-group them.

Comment: Also disable the move handles/functionality for the child shapes so they can't be moved independently.

Comment: Just a quick response to your soapbox, at times you want the user to be able to move around a group of objects (with ease), but be able to individually select them once moved. Example: I'm currently designing a table seating feature. I want the user to be able to move the whole table around, but also want them to be able to select an individual seat at the table.

Comment: @dearsina: fair point. I'd counter that when you want to select a seat at the table you want to ungroup the table-and-seats object so that you can interact with just a seat. I'd love to see how you implement your example.

Answer (score 1):

I believe _objects is to be used internally only and may thus change in the future.

To me it group.item(indexOfItem) seems to be the way

Comment: In addition, to get all objects you can call `group.getObjects() `

Answer (score 1):

So I had this scenario where I have multiple images in a box. Those all images move along with the box (as a group) but user should also be able to select an individual image and move it.

Basically I wanted to select individual objects (in my case images) of group, I did it like this:

```
groupImages.forEach(image => image.on('mousedown', function (e) {
    var group = e.target;
    if (group && group._objects) {
        var thisImage = group._objects.indexOf(image);
        var item = group._objects[thisImage];//.find(image);
        canvas.setActiveObject(item);
    }
}));
```

groupImages could be list of objects which you want to select individually.